# Swift custom back button in navigation bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, back-button

I am trying to use a custom image for my back button in the navigation bar. I am using the below code, which adds the image, but also keeps the text "Back" in the button. I want to also remove the text. Can I do that?

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "icon-back")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "icon-back")
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try code below :-)

```
func SetBackBarButtonCustom()
{
    //Back buttion
    let btnLeftMenu: UIButton = UIButton()
    btnLeftMenu.setImage(UIImage(named: "back_arrow"), for: UIControlState())
    btnLeftMenu.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UIViewController.onClcikBack), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    btnLeftMenu.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 33/2, height: 27/2)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnLeftMenu)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
}

func onClcikBack()
{
    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko please check i have update Ans for swift 3.

Comment: Thanks it is work, but how to set text next to image? I tried `.setTitle("Cancel",for: .normal)` but it is doesn't work... I tried increase button frame, but also without success ... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you try set image and text together ?

Comment: of course, but it only presents image... Than I tried remove image and left only text and instead of text I got three dot `...` , than I tried increase button frame twice, but anyway `...` . Did you try to set text for yourself?

Comment: Try this :- btnLeftMenu.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 44)

Comment: ok, it is works only I set single text, but if I set image + text, I see only image... I tried increase width up to 160, but it is just scratching image, text invisible

Comment: Try image set in background.

Comment: ?? Background... But I need Image and next to Image I need to have text, it  is exactly what I need

Comment: btnLeftMenu.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "back_arrow"), forState: .normal)

Comment: did you tried this approach? This approach set image as a background , but  as I said above I need set text next to image... Did you get my idea?

Comment: Aleksey Timoshchenko no need to set frame explicitly, Instead you can call sizeToFit() on button directly.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to add Back button in every UIViewController then you can add the code in UIViewController extension else you can use addBackButton() directly as follows.

```
extension UIViewController {

    func addBackButton() {
        let btnLeftMenu: UIButton = UIButton()
        let image = UIImage(named: "backButtonImage");
        btnLeftMenu.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        btnLeftMenu.setTitle("Back".localized, for: .normal);
        btnLeftMenu.sizeToFit()
        btnLeftMenu.addTarget(self, action: #selector (backButtonClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnLeftMenu)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
    }

    func backButtonClick(sender : UIButton) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true);
    }
}
```

Make sure you should add the following file "backButtonImage.png" in your app bundle.

Call this method self.addBackButton()in your viewDidLoad method of your custom UIViewController class like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.addBackButton()
 }
```

Note : if you don't add addBackButton Method in extension then you will need to add this method directly in the class and set target and Selector accordingly.